# How to use WIA to get an image scanned using NETWORK printer

Tags: c#, printing, wia, twain, scanning

myself and some other devs at my company have made an app in C# to scan an image from a printer/scanner, that image gets saved somewhere then we want to print it using the "print button" in our app, we want to use  TWAIN and WIA to get this done, however all WIA info we have points to this being done via a USB printer and we want it done via a network printer, we know how to do it via a USB printer but want it done the other way, so does anyone have any idea of an API to use in order for this to work with a network printer or how to get TWAIN or WIA to work that way?

Any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: If you use TWAIN, as long as your network printer has a TWAIN driver and it can be accessed from the client machine, you should be able to scan from the device. You can use Twacker to test. http://kb.dynamsoft.com/questions/654/How+to+use+TWACKER+to+check+my+scanner%3F

Answer (score 2):

Normally you don't have to worry about how the device connected(USB/network). WIA or Twain interface should work in same way. You have install correct driver for the device. In WIA you can add a network scanner using wsd . For Twain you have to have vendor network twain driver for same.